# Não consigo utilizar char '&' Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt

Estou tentando retornar uma QString, que sera usada como uma URL e preciso usar '&' como um separador na URL. Porém, quando o caracter é colocado na QString, ele faz uma quebra na URL e o que deveria aparecer após o '&' não aparece.

```
retorno = "start http://localhost:5000/robo/?Nome="+nome+"&Capital="+capital;
```

No caso, 'nome' e 'capital' são QStrings declaradas anteriormente. Já tentei declarar um QChar com o código ASCII do '&' e tenho o mesmo erro.

Comment: Não consigo ver problema, pode ser em algo onde está usando a variável. Um [mcve] seria útil.

Comment: O retorno é enviado ao sistema da seguinte maneira
system(retorno.toStdString().c_str());

Comment: será que não é problema de interação com o console? Provavelmente eu nem faria isso

Comment: independente do problema do &, provavelmente seria melhos no seu caso usar os recursos da própria Qt (ou mesmo nativos do OS) para iniciar um processo, em vez do "start".

Answer (score 2):

Isso ocorre porque o `&` (E comercial - ampersand) é usado pelo sistema para separar dois comandos em uma mesma linha, é um caractere "especial", assim como pipe (`|`) e os paranteses (`(` e `)`), e todos podem ser escapdos com `^`

**No entanto** se esta usando Qt, ele já tem funções prontas para isto, que evita você ter que ter este trabalho de ficar escapando os caracteres, por exemplo:

### Usando [`QProcess`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html)

Usando QProcess com QStringList você pode passar os argumentos e o próprio "Qt" vai escapar eles pra ti:

```
retorno = "http://localhost:5000/robo/?Nome="+nome+"&Capital="+capital;

QProcess process;
process.start("start", QStringList() << retorno);
```

O que provavelmente já deve resolver, no entanto é interessante notar que o próprio Qt tem uma classe chamada `QDesktopServices`

### Usando [`QDesktopServices`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopservices.html)

Que já tem o objetivo de interagir com funções do sistema operacional, ou seja se você portar o seu programa para Linux ou OSX não vai precisar mudar nada nesta parte (vai depender do que mais você fez), exemplo com `openUrl` (`QUrl` é necessário):

```
retorno = "http://localhost:5000/robo/?Nome="+nome+"&Capital="+capital;

QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl(retorno));
```

Pronto, assim ele vai buscar o programa do sistema que esta associado ao protocolo da URL, no caso HTTP provavelmente irá abrir o navegador padrão e também não vai precisar de "escapes" (como o `^`).

Answer (score 1):

O problema estava no caracter '&' que era passado para o console. Coloquei '^' antes de cada '&' da QString e o console entendeu como um caracter ao invés de um comando.

Comment: O caractere `&` tem um significado especial no Qt. Ele é usado para indicar teclas de atalho e controlar os focos dos botoes,